# How to make a probabilistic sense of the semigroup of a positive operator

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the operator $\mathcal{L}$ acting on the function $f:\{0,1\}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined as following: $$\mathcal{L}f(x)=f(1-x)-f(x)$$
This is the infinitesimal generator of a continuous time random walk $X_t$ on the space state $\{0,1\}$ with jump rate equal to 1. We can define the semigroup $P_t$ associated with the operator $\mathcal{L}$  as $$P_t=\exp{\mathcal{L}t}$$ and this would have a nice interpretation with random walk, i.e. $$P_t f(x) = E_x[f(X_t)]=P(X_t=0|X_0=x)f(0)+P(X_t=1|X_0=x)f(1)$$
I would like to know if there is a probabilistic interpretation of the semigroup $P^{*}_{t}=\exp{-\mathcal{L}t}$. Is this just a time reversal?

I am quite puzzled by this since $f(0)P_t f(0) + f(1) P_t f(1) \rightarrow 0$ and $f(0)P^{*}_t f(0) + f(1) P^{*}_t f(1) \rightarrow \infty$.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: $-\mathcal L$ is not a generator of a Markov process, as it does not satisfy the maximum principle.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say it is satisfying enough for you to get the bounty if nobody else answers. Post it as an answer if you want the reward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-\mathcal{L}$ is not a generator of a Markov process, since it does not satisfy the maximum principle. Indeed, let $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = -1$. Then $x=0$ is a point of maximum, but $-\mathcal Lf(0) = 1>0$.